# error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab

What should I do to not get this error in MATLAB?

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
>   logicals.

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood from your code, you are trying to compute the BER for different modulation schemes. For that, you are trying to use the right-tail probability function, *Q(x)*. To do so, you first need to define *Q(x)*. It is related to the `erf` and `erfc` function. Kindly have a look at these functions in MATLAB help and implement *Q(x)*.

In the given code, you define ***Q=0.007***, which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I got the  output graph as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're trying to index ***Q*** which is not a vector but a single variable.

The second problem is that even if it was indeed a vector, you're indexing it by `sqrt(EbN0)` which isn't an int. You can't index a vector by a fractional number (unless you interpolate).

In general, Matlab's error descriptions are pretty clear :

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

That means that your indice is neither a positive integer nor logical.